# Not able to see the current open project path in visual studio code terminal

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have created an angular project in `C:\angular_workspace` using command `ng new myProject` and it is successfully created.
Now I went to the above location i.e. `C:\angular_workspace` in the console and typed the command `code .` . Now the project opened in the Visual Studio code.
After that in the terminal it is showing like below.
[image]
It is not showing the currently opened project path i.e. `C:\angular_workspace\myProject` .
Could you please help me how to get the path in the terminal so that I can execute all my angular/ng commands from terminal itself.

Answer (score 0):

This may be occurs by Windows Exec in VS. Set terminal path in VS terminal settings.

**Linux:** `xtermC:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

**macOS:** `Terminal.app`

**Windows:** `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMYBK.png)

Comment: I have set the path as you said, and reopened the visual studio code but still not able to see the current open project path.